# Placing different marker icons for different users in android application on GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

i want to add points on a the map in android application , i get the points (Latitude,Longitude) from web service and want to place them on the map with markers but the problem that i have two kinds of users so i want to place one of them with a marker different than the other users

Answer (score 0):

you could do some thing like that:

```
for (Task tempTask : SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository())
{
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(tempTask.getLatitude(),tempTask.getLongtitude());
    if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_WAITING))
    {
        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_blue)));
    }
    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_IN_PROGRESS))
    {
        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_bordo)));
    }
    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_ON_THE_WAY))
    {
        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_turkiz)));
    }
    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_COMPLETE))
    {
        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_orange)));
    }
    else if (tempTask.getStatus().contentEquals(TasksListActivity.STATUS_FAILED))
    {
        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_purpul)));
    }
}
```

as you see I am setting a different icon with a different color for the marker depending on it's status.

you could do some thing similar, just change the check you preform.

Comment: newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_blue)));  I have errors in MarkerOptions ---->MarkerOption cannot be resolved as a type.

Comment: add this import to you map activity class:
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;